# How to apply resolveExtensions configuration to exposed components using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-module-federation

I have used **resolveExtensions** in webpack config as follows.

```
const commonOpts = {
  isExternalEnv: true,
  outputPath: 'dist/production/www',
  resolveExtensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.json', '.jsx', '.scss']
}
```

It is working fine for normal components.

As i am using module federation concepts in project. So i am exposing components like below for which **resolveExtensions** configuration is not working.

```
const commonOpts = {
  isExternalEnv: true,
  outputPath: 'dist/production/www',
  resolveExtensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.json', '.jsx', '.scss'],
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                    options: {
                        resources: require('./src/styles/common/index.js'),
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
  },
  moduleFederationOpts: {
    name: 'MyApp',
    filename: 'js/my-app-entry.js',
    exposes: {
        './myapp': './src/app.js',
        './myAppBlock': './src/modules/blocks/myBlock.js',
    },
  },
}
```

How can we apply **resolveExtensions** configuration to exposed components?

Answer (score 0):

If you using Webpack 5. Try this!

```js
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.ts', '.json', '.jsx', '.scss'],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes. But it's not working for exposes components.